'Bearer'(JWT TOKEN) is missing in value of Authorization key inside Header while submit the request from Swagger UI using Nodejs
I'm using the swagger autogen openAPI 3.0 with NodeJs and facing the issue while submitting the request from Swagger UI is that Bearer prefix unable to come with token. Kindly suggest me right path to solve this issue.

Is any way that could add prefix Bearer implicitly while submitting the request.
My swagger docs configuration  for Authorization are given below


are you using express?

yes, I'm using express
